# Load Options ROM using Windows driver?

Tags: windows, bios, uefi

Why on earth? What? Well, I have some SCSI hardware that won't run with Windows 10 and a UEFI boot.  My PC also doesn't seem to load the Options ROM if I run in insecure UEFI mode.  So I wondered if technically I could write a Windows 10 driver that could do what the BIOS doesn't.

Clearly, I can't 'load before OS' to allow a 'boot from SCSI' but I might at least be able to make SCSI disks and hardware active after Windows boots.

So before I head off on a wild goose chase, is this technically possible?  Can I, for example, run code to hook interrupts from a Windows driver running in the kernel?

Comment: Do you know why the option ROM is not being loaded by the OS? If you have an OS installed on the SCSI device, can it be seen from UEFI? Also, the option ROM will have been built targeting a specific environment, like legacy BIOS or UEFI. If you can, try putting your UEFI into compatibility mode. You'll find the option to do so in the setup menu -- sometimes referred to as "CSM".

Comment: I've tried both legacy and 'insecure UEFI' which is also claimed to try and load BIOS style Options ROMs but neither seem to do anything.  On an older PC, I see the usual Adaptec messages as the Option ROM loads but not on my newer PC.  I've not found any way to determine whether the Option ROM really is, or not, loaded but my assumption is that it's not.